# Unable to insert array relationship in Hasura / GraphQL with my mutation

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo, hasura

I am using the Apollo iOS client to connect to our Hasura/postgress docker environment.

I am trying to create an object and fill it's relationship array. However, I get an error message in my `switch result` statement telling me:

```
variable subtasks of type [SubtaskReport_insert_input]! is used in position expecting SubtaskReport_arr_rel_insert_input
```

I've tried changing the type from `SubtaskReport_insert_input` to `SubtaskReport_arr_rel_insert_input` but There's no `SubtaskReport_arr_rel_insert_input` type generated by the code generator.

How does one create this array so I can execute the mutation successfully?

My mutation graphql is as follows:

```
    mutation addTaskReport($category: String!, $duration: Int!, $interval: Int!, $ppgs: String!, $status: String!, $taskDescription: String!, $task_id: uuid!, $zone_name: String!, $subtasks: [SubtaskReport_insert_input]!) {
      insert_TaskReport(
        objects: {
          category: $category,
          duration: $duration,
          interval: $interval,
          ppgs: $ppgs,
          status: $status,
          taskDescription: $taskDescription,
          task_id: $task_id,
          zone_name: $zone_name
          subtasks: $subtasks
        }) {
        returning {
          id
        }
      }
    }
```

The iOS code that I'm using to construct and send the mutation:

```
    func addTaskReport(for task: Task) {
      guard
        let category = task.category,
        let duration = task.duration,
        let interval = task.interval,
        let ppgsSet = task.ppgs,
        let zoneName = task.zoneOfTask?.name,
        let taskDescription = task.summary
        else {
          return
      }

      let taskReportId = UUID().uuidString.lowercased()

      var subtaskReports = [SubtaskReport_arr_rel_insert_input]()
      for subtask in task.subtasks as! Set<Subtask> {
        let subtaskReportId = UUID().uuidString.lowercased()
        let subtaskReport = SubtaskReport_insert_input(id: subtaskReportId, status: false, taskReportId: taskReportId, title: subtask.title)
        subtaskReports.append(subtaskReport)
      }

      let ppgs = ppgsSet as Set<PersonalProtectionGear>
      let ppgsStringArray = ppgs.compactMap({$0.name})
      let ppgsString = Array(ppgsStringArray).joined(separator:" ")

      self.apollo.perform(mutation: AddTaskReportMutation(
        category: category,
        duration: Int(duration),
        interval: Int(interval),
        ppgs: ppgsString,
        status: "open",
        taskDescription: taskDescription,
        task_id: taskReportId,
        zone_name: zoneName,
        subtasks: subtaskReports)
      ) { (result) in
        switch result {
          case .success(let graphQLResult):
            print("Simon Says graphQLResult \(graphQLResult)")//TODO: Remove
            break
          case .failure(let error):
            print("Simon Says error \(error)")//TODO: Remove
            break
        }
        print("Simon Says BreakHere")//TODO: Remove
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the `data` key in front of the related resource (`subtasks`) should work for you! Also, suggestion: use `[SubtaskReport_insert_input!]!` as well. It's the expected type of the `*_array_rel_input`.

Updated the query as such:

```
+   mutation addTaskReport($category: String!, $duration: Int!, $interval: Int!, $ppgs: String!, $status: String!, $taskDescription: String!, $task_id: uuid!, $zone_name: String!, $subtasks: [SubtaskReport_insert_input!]!) {
      insert_TaskReport(
        objects: {
          category: $category,
          duration: $duration,
          interval: $interval,
          ppgs: $ppgs,
          status: $status,
          taskDescription: $taskDescription,
          task_id: $task_id,
          zone_name: $zone_name
+         subtasks: {
+          data: $subtasks
+         }
        }) {
        returning {
          id
        }
      }
    }
```

Relevant documentation: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/insert.html#insert-an-object-along-with-its-related-objects-through-relationships

I definitely recommend using the GraphiQL interface to debug the query (vs. your code) because it gives graphql type suggestions and checking, can be found by visiting http://localhost:9695/api-explorer or http://localhost:8080/api-explorer.

Comment: Thnx for the help. Worked like a charm. P.s. visiting the api-explorer gave me a "{"path":"$","error":"resource does not exist","code":"not-found"}" warning....

Comment: Great! Hmm @TychoPandelaar maybe open a new question? Likely related to how Hasura is running locally - there are some Github issues around that error as well.